# Ошибка при socket.send(): TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, сокет

Есть сервер принимающий ряд русскоязычных команд.
Было принято решение написать клиент на Python с использованием сокетов.
Проблема в том, что `s.send()` вообще не хочет обрабатывать кириллицу ссылаясь на:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Пробовал использовать `s.send(text.encode())`, но серверная часть не обрабатывает этот пакет.

Я действительно гуглил, но не нашел решения.
Возможно ли отправить подобный пакет в чистом виде?
Возможно есть альтернативы socket?

Comment: Для начала определитесь, в какой кодировке должны находиться ваши русскоязычные команды (это и сишечек и вообще любых ЯП касается, не только питона)

Comment: В идеале я хочу использовать примитивный ASCII .

Comment: Вы хотите невозможно, в ASCII нет русских символов

Comment: *"Пробовал использовать s.send(text.encode()), но серверная часть не обрабатывает этот пакет"* — что значит *"не обрабатывает"*? Что вы ожидали должно было произойти? Что вместо этого происходит?  Что ваш сервер ожидает? По какому протоколу сервер работает? http? У вас есть рабочий клиент на любом языке?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать:

```
socket.send(b'Твой текст')
```

или

```
socket.send('Твой текст'.encode('utf-8'))
```